# start up of apache server during bootup

Tags: 12.04

When I need to login to Linux, I need to start the apache webserver automatically.Which means I need to add the startup script part of bash scripts and include in the bootup scripts?

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't this automatically set up when you `apt-get install apache`? Anyway, have a look at the /etc/init.d scripts... I believe using a simple one as a model for your new apache initialization script will be quite easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should start automatically at boot when you install from software center, or using `apt-get`.

If you install from source code, you want to add its init script to the approriate run level. The init script is typically /etc/init.d/apache2 where you could manually run /etc/init.d/apache2 start to start it.

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults
```

will make th job

Comment: Thanks..I'm basically trying to understand how to setup a bash script that will automatically run while bootup